# How to think of cohomology classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, intuition

I guess some of my problems come from the fact that I can hardly visualise cohomology. For homology in dimensions 1–3, I claim to have at least some intuition what homology classes look like, and when two cocycles are homologous.  But for cohomology, I mostly have no idea how the cohomology classes, once I look e.g. at a CW- or $\Delta$-complex, look like.

For $H^1$ of manifolds with a $\Delta$-complex structure, I know that I can think of cocycles as closed loops crossing transversally through edges, assigning the value 1 to all edges they cross, and 0 to the others. How does this idea extend to non-manifold complexes, e.g., if more then two 2-cells are adjacent to a 1-cell? How do cocycles look like if they represent non-trivial cohomology? How do cohomologous cocycles look like? And how about $H^2$…?

Comment: Very roughly, cohomology is dual to homology, so you can think of cohomology classes as an assignment of values to closed loops, surfaces etc., so that homologous loops get the same value, etc. (OK, in reality it's more complicated than that, but it's a rough idea.)